# What kind of video terminal is the default terminal emulating in Linux nowadays?

Tags: linux, terminal

What kind of video terminal is the default terminal emulating in Linux nowadays? VT100 or VT520? Or maybe other kinds?

Comment: The Linux console is terminal type "linux", which is mostly ANSI terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It usually is the ANSI terminal (or a superset) accepting [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Usually the environment (see [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html)...) has the `TERM` environment variable, e.g. set to [`xterm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm). See also [termcap](https://www.gnu.org/software/termutils/manual/termcap-1.3/html_mono/termcap.html).

In practice, use a library like [ncurses](https://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/ncurses.html) or [readline](https://www.gnu.org/software/readline/)

Answer (score 0):

It is "mostly" ANSI, as noted in the [console_codes](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) manpage.  The most notable exception is the color palette sequence: it lacks the "final character" which allows applications to tell when the escape sequence has ended (without knowing specific information about the terminal).